# Can I install Ubuntu 12.10 on an Acer Aspire laptop?

Tags: system-installation, acer

I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.10, and I want to install it on my Acer Aspire laptop.

- Intel Pentium Dual Core Processor @ 1.86 GHz
- 2,5GB of RAM
- 500GB HDD
- Mobile Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X3100

My question is: can I install Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop with those specs?

Comment: ii would recommend running a dual boot option so you can do a back to back comparison

Comment: Please include the model name of your laptop (it should be on the bottom of your laptop or on the receipt). This will help other users find this question.

Comment: Maybe you would like to try Xubuntu instead, your 2.5 GB ram will work better.

Comment: I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 to my laptop Acer Aspire one. Its impossible for me to install it. The download dont open for installing. Any proposals?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest booting the laptop with the Ubuntu 12.10 CD and selecting the:
**Try Ubuntu Before You Install** option.

That way your laptop will boot into Ubuntu without making any changes to your laptop and will give you a good indication of the compatibility of your laptop hardware with Ubuntu.

Judging from your laptop specs though I do not see a problem with Ubuntu 12.10 working on your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it should work. Ubuntu 12.04.01 works quite well. I have seen it working on one of my cousin sister's laptop and she has had no problems using it. I would suggest you replacing the default Sata hard disk with a SSD and upgrade the RAM if you can for better response.

You may also find that battery life is a little lesser as compared to Windows. On a Windows 7, laptop battery will last for about 4 hours. With a Ubuntu, it will last you a 20 to 30 minutes lesser. Quite weird, but I have seen it in action

Also keep in mind, it is not a performance laptop, so things you could do with this laptop are not heavy duty stuff - with Windows or with Ubuntu.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have 12.10 running on an unmodified Asus eee 701. It's sluggish but it works. So chances are it'll run on your system. Testing with a live cd/USB is probably a good idea!